# Tables wont align in one row

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I'm creating a box, inside of which is an image and 3 tables. This is all displayed in shiny dashboard.

```
###Data 
Skill = c("Wood", "Metal", "Speech", "Garden","Design", "Stats", "Farming", "Tattoos")

Score = c("+33.7%", "+14.8%", "+20.8%", "+28.17%", "+12.9%", "+19.9%", "+27.3%", "+28.1%")
no1_A = data.frame(Skill, Score)
Score =c("+37.1%", "+14.2%", "+19.3%", "+26.3%", "+19.5%", "+11.8%", "+15.3%", "+26.2%")
no1_B = data.frame(Skill, Score)
Score = c("+3.1%", "+22.2%", "+17.3%", "+25.3%", "+11.5%", "+21.0%", "+14.6%", "+25.2%")
no1_C = data.frame(Skill, Score)


###UI
box(title = "",
    status = "primary",
    solidHeader = F,
    collapsible = F,
    width = 12,
    fluidRow(
      column(width=2, align="center",
             img(src="no1.jpeg", width=100)),
      column(width = 4,offset = 0, style='padding:0px;',
             box(title = "Table A",
                 div(tableOutput("no1_A")), style = "font-size:80%")),
      column(width = 4,offset = 0, style='padding:0px;',
             box(title = "Table B",
                 div(tableOutput("no1_B")),style = "font-size:80%" )),
      column(width = 4,offset = 0, style='padding:0px;',
             box(title = "Table C",
                 div(tableOutput("no1_C")), style = "font-size:80%"))
    ))


### Server
output$no1_A <-renderTable(no1_survey)
output$no1_B <-renderTable(no1_ws)
output$no1_C <-renderTable(no1_int)
```

I want all the three tables to be aligned in one row. I tried changing the size of the font to make them smaller, but it's not working and there is definitely enough room for all 3 of them in a row + the image.

[image: What it looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column widths in your row add up to 14, when 12 if the maximum. Take the table widths down to 3 each and then this should sort it.